# Nodes in the collapsible tree get overlapped. D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, d3.js

I am implementing a d3 code in power bi for a collapsible tree. Each node in my tree is a rectangular box. But for some reason the nodes get overlapped if the node size is large. Here is my code:

```
// ADD: translate function for the data 
function toJSON(data) {
    var flare = { name: "All Products", children: [] },
        levels = ["productcategory","productsubcategory"];

    // For each data row, loop through the expected levels traversing the output tree
    data.forEach(function(d){
        // Keep this as a reference to the current level
        var depthCursor = flare.children;
        // Go down one level at a time
        levels.forEach(function( property, depth ){

            // Look to see if a branch has already been created
            var index;
            depthCursor.forEach(function(child,i){
                if ( d[property] == child.name ) index = i;
            });
            // Add a branch if it isn't there
            if ( isNaN(index) ) {
                depthCursor.push({ name : d[property], children : []});
                index = depthCursor.length - 1;
            }
            // Now reference the new child array as we go deeper into the tree
            depthCursor = depthCursor[index].children;
            // This is a leaf, so add the last element to the specified branch
            if ( depth === levels.length - 1 ) depthCursor.push({ name : d.product, size : d.revenue, revenue : d.revenue});
        });
    });
    // End of conversion
    return flare;
}

// Aggregate the revenue at each level
function aggregateRevenue(node) {
    if(node.children) {
        node.children.forEach(function(child) {
            aggregateRevenue(child);
            node.revenue = d3.sum(node.children, function(d) { return d.revenue; });
        });
    }
}

// Set the margins
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = pbi.width - margin.left - margin.right,   // ALTER: Changed fixed width with the 'pbi.width' variable
    height = pbi.height - margin.top - margin.bottom; // ALTER: Changed fixed height with the 'pbi.height' variable

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });


// Zoom functionality:
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
    svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

// SVG creation
var svg =  d3.select("#chart")                           // ALTER: Select SVG object; no need to create it
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)   // ALTER: Add complete width
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom) // ALTER: Add complete height
    .call(zoom)  // Add zoom behavior here
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// ALTER: Replaced the d3.json function with the pbi variant: pbi.dsv
pbi.dsv(function(data) {
    var flare = toJSON(data); // ALTER: add extra convertion step to parent/child JSON
    root = flare;
    aggregateRevenue(flare);
    root.x0 = height / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    
    // collapse the tree
    function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapse);
            d.children = null;
        }
    }
        
    root.children.forEach(collapse);
    update(root);
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);
  
  // Total revenue ( to calculate individual perncentages )
  var totalRevenue = d3.sum(data, function(d) { return d.revenue; }); 
 
  // Append rectangular node
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 80)
    .attr("x", -75)
    .attr("y", -40)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? pbi.colors[0] : pbi.colors[1]; });

  // Append name of the node
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -15);

  // Append the green stacked bar line
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "percentage")
    .attr("width", function(d) { return ((d.revenue / totalRevenue) * 100).toFixed(2); })
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("x", -50)
    .attr("y", -5)
    .attr("fill", "green");
  
  // Append the blue stacked bar line
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "non-percentage")
    .attr("width", function(d) { return 100 - ((d.revenue / totalRevenue) * 100).toFixed(2); })
    .attr("height", 10)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return ((d.revenue / totalRevenue) * 100).toFixed(2) - 50; })
    .attr("y", -5)
    .attr("fill", "blue");
  
  // Append the text for green bar
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", -70)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .text(function(d) { return ((d.revenue / totalRevenue) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"; })
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("font-weight", "bold");
  
  // Append the text for blue bar
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 35)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .text(function(d) { return (100 - ((d.revenue / totalRevenue) * 100)).toFixed(2) + "%"; })
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("font-weight", "bold");
  
  // Append node's revenue inside the node
  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return "Revenue = $" + d.revenue; })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 15);
  
  // Append % of total share shared by the node
  //nodeEnter.append("text")
    //.text(function(d) { return "% Total Share = " + ((d.revenue / totalRevenue) * 100).toFixed(2) + "%"; })
    //.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    //.attr("dominant-baseline", "central")
    //.style("fill", "white")
    //.style("font-weight", "bold")
    //.attr("x", 0)
    //.attr("y", 15);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

I also tried of following code but this does not seem to work also:

```
var treemap = d3.tree()
  .size([10*height, width])
  .separation(function separation(a, b) { return a.parent == b.parent ? 2 : 2; });
```

A help in this regard shall be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the node size to your box(rectangle size) that is 80

```
var treemap = d3.tree()
  .size([80, width])
  .separation(function separation(a, b) { return a.parent == b.parent ? 2 : 2; });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).